# Prove that $\int_Bg(z)dz=\int_{B_1}g(z)dz+\int_{B_2}g(z)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

> Let $B$,$B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ be non-interesecfting simple closed curves, such that $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ are contained inside $B$. Let $g$ be analytic in the region between these curves, and on the curves. I want to prove using only the Cauchy-Goursat theorem and basic properties of integrals that 
>   $$\int_Bg(z)dz=\int_{B_1}g(z)dz+\int_{B_2}g(z)dz$$

My attempt at the proof;
First let the direction along $B$ be anti-clockwise, then since $g$ satisfies the conditions for the cauchy-goursat theorem we have that $$\int_{B}g(z)dz=0$$
Now let the direction along $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ be clockwise, then by the cauchy goursat theorem again we have that $$\int_{-B_{1}}g(z)dz+\int_{-B_{2}}g(z)dz=0\implies -\int_{B_1}g(z)dz-\int_{B_2}g(z)dz=0$$ $$\implies \int_{B_1}g(z)dz+\int_{B_2}g(z)dz=0=\int_{B}g(z)dz=\sum_{i=1}^{2}\int_{B_{i}}g(z)dz$$
 as required

Could someone tell me if this is incorrect (and how to fix it if it is) and if it is correct?

Comment: Does anyone know if this is correct ?

Comment: As I'm unsure if it's correct

Comment: The step asserting that $\int_Bg(z)dz=0$ is already wrong. For a counterexample, consider $g(z)=\frac1z$, $B$ some large circle around $0$, $B_1$ some smaller circle around $0$, and $B_2$ some other circle included in the annulus between $B$ and $B_1$. Since the misunderstanding is basic, I suggest to reread much more carefully the results in your complex analysis notes before going further.

Comment: For example, the condition that a function defined on some region is analytic on some curve bounding the region is simply meaningless.

Comment: @Did I thought that the conditions imposed on the function g in the question are those that satisfy the Cauchy goursat theorem ,  would you be able to suggest a place to start the proof ?

Comment: Yes I would be. And actually I did exactly that in my two previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proposition as it is stated now does not hold. $B_1$ or $B_2$ is allowed to be inside of the other, resulting in 
$$\int_Bg(z)dz=\int_{B_1}g(z)dz=\int_{B_2}g(z)dz$$

Now we add the condition that neither of $B_1$ and $B_2$ resides inside of the other, as well as that $g$ is analytic in a (open and connected) domain $D$ that contains the union of the following two sets. The first set is the intersection of, the outerior of $B_1$ and $B_2$, and the interior of $B$. The second is $B\cup B_1\cup B_2$. This will produce the desired equation.

Proof: Transform the domain homeomorphically so that $B\cup B_1\cup B_2$ becomes the circles depicted in the graph below. Then take the contour $C$ as shown in the graph below running counter-clockwise on the large circle, clockwise on the smaller circles, only letting the distance between the gap be zero. [image: below]

Take the contour $\gamma$ that is the image of $C$ on the original domain, apply Cauchy-Goursat theorem to $g$ on $D$ and contour $\gamma$ 
$$0=\int_\gamma g(z)dz=\int_B g(z)dz-\int_{B_1}g(z)dz-\int_{B_2}g(z)dz+0+0$$
where the last two $0$'s signifies the integration on the parallel sides of the straight "streets" in the graph in opposite directions which results in cancellation of the integration on those parts of $\gamma$.

Now we have obtained the desired equation.

Comment: Would you be able to expand on your proof to make it a bit clearer I think I understand but I'm unsure with your diagram

Comment: @Gibberish: Is the latest edit any clearer?

Comment: Yea a bit , is this basically using the contour deformation to prove the result ?

Comment: @Gibberish: You got it. It is just to make the contour topologically equivalent to a circle.

Comment: May I ask what direction the contours needs to be

Comment: Or is that irrelevant

Comment: @Gibberish: Did you read the clockwise and counterclockwise directions in my proof?

Comment: Sorry yes I miss read that part thank you very much

Comment: Is there any proof that does not require the diagram or the use of deformation ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72196/discussion-between-hans-and-gibberish).

Comment: @Gibberish: Are you asking how to describe the contour $C$ in the diagram with only words or how to describe its image $\gamma$ which could be a complicated labyrinth of curves? If it is the former, yes, it is easy to describe it in words which you can try. If it is the latter, yes, you can write an algorithm to do that, but the procedures need to be proved to be legitimate if rigor is desired. There are certain proofs without deformation of a circular contour. But are you not supposed to use Cauchy-Goursat theorem?